# SQL Backup very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I takes like an hour to backup my 24GB database. I put the backup on the same disk as the location of the actual SQL database, but I dont think thats the cause.

When I execute `exec sp_who2`, here is the result:

[image]

And here is the result of

```
SELECT  wt.session_id, ot.task_state, wt.wait_type, wt.wait_duration_ms, wt.blocking_session_id, wt.resource_description, es.[host_name], es.[program_name] FROM  sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks  wt  INNER  JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ot ON ot.task_address = wt.waiting_task_address INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON es.session_id = wt.session_id WHERE es.is_user_process =  1
```

[image]

Here is the perfmon window:

[image]

How can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: Start with the fact that the disc is overloading ;) Get a much faster disc subsystem. Helps to move read and write operations to separate spindles as per my answer (I.e. do not write the backup to the same disc).

Answer (score 5):

> I put the backup on the same disk as the location of the actual SQL
>   database, but I dont think thats the cause.

Reality check - that is absolutely one reason that a backup like that is slow.

Discs break down in IO when you do multiple operations at the same time. Even worse so when it is "the disc" not "the disc array in a high performance raid 10".

Your head is busy moving back and forh between database operations, reading for backup and writing to the file.